# Run scripts for @media print only

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic page, that needs some formatting when it is printed. Currently it has some inline styling, that needs to be removed. I can do something like:

```
$('.myElements').removeAttr('style');
```

However, I need to run this code ONLY when the page is printed.

I do use CSS **@media print**, but I need to be able to detect media type from withing my document, in order to remove inline styles with jQuery.

What is the best way to execute this code for print only?

Comment: enquire.js could be worth looking at: http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/

Comment: @Matt - you should write this in the form of answer.

Comment: I'd like to keep a simple local code instead of adding yet another plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `@media print` for this. USing this you can write custom css, which will apply at the time of print only

```
<style>

@media print
  {
  p{font-size:20px;color:red;}
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Yes, I am using this in CSS, however I need to be able to detect media type from withing my document, in order to remove inline styles with jQuery.